# SMTP error '554 5.7.1 Relay access denied' with using postfix

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix, smtp, courier

I have been trying to setup a mail server on my ubuntu vServer for the last couple of days. I use postfix with mySQL and Courier. For webmail, I use roundcube.

I can receive emails to my address, but when I try to send an email using SMTP, I get the following error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZtmr.png
It doesn't matter what address I send it to, I always get the same error. EDIT: I forgot to say that I can send mail to myself, only outbound mail doesn't work.

Now after some googling, I found out this site: https://www.gammadyne.com/relaying_denied.htm which basically says that this error occurs when the user isn't authenticating himself correctly. I am new to postfix and smpt, so I have not clue where to look for fixing this error.

This is the error message from /var/log/mail.log when I try to send a mail thorugh roundcube (cybershit.de is my domain, bnry.de is a second domain that links to the same IP, though cybershit.de is being used for the mail services):

```
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from vps1908220.fastwebserver.de[62.141.44.212]: 554 5.7.1 <example@example.com>: Relay access denied; from=<staddle@cybershit.de> to=<example@example.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<bnry.de>
```

When I try to send a mail through Thunderbird, I get a SMTP error but nothing more specific.

**I very much appreciate any help, I can post any other log files / config files if needed. Thank you!**

Here are my config files:
**postfix main.cf:**

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = cybershit.de ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no


# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings

#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023, permit 
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.cybershit.de
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = 
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
#mynetworks = localhost
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

# Virtual Mailbox Domain Settings

virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = 51200000
virtual_minimum_uid = 5000
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_transport = virtual

# Additional for quota support

virtual_create_maildirsize = yes
virtual_mailbox_extended = yes
virtual_mailbox_limit_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_limit_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit_override = yes
virtual_maildir_limit_message = Sorry, the your maildir has overdrawn your diskspace quota, please free up some of spaces of your mailbox try again.
virtual_overquota_bounce = yes
```

**Roundcubes config.inc.php:**

```
<?php

/*
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Local configuration for the Roundcube Webmail installation.           |
|                                                                       |
| This is a sample configuration file only containing the minimum       |
| setup required for a functional installation. Copy more options       |
| from defaults.inc.php to this file to override the defaults.          |
|                                                                       |
| This file is part of the Roundcube Webmail client                     |
| Copyright (C) 2005-2013, The Roundcube Dev Team                       |
|                                                                       |
| Licensed under the GNU General Public License version 3 or            |
| any later version with exceptions for skins & plugins.                |
| See the README file for a full license statement.                     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
*/

$config = array();

/* Do not set db_dsnw here, use dpkg-reconfigure roundcube-core to configure database ! */
include_once("/etc/roundcube/debian-db-roundcube.php");

// The IMAP host chosen to perform the log-in.
// Leave blank to show a textbox at login, give a list of hosts
// to display a pulldown menu or set one host as string.
// To use SSL/TLS connection, enter hostname with prefix ssl:// or tls://
// Supported replacement variables:
// %n - hostname ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
// %t - hostname without the first part
// %d - domain (http hostname $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] without the first part)
// %s - domain name after the '@' from e-mail address provided at login screen
// For example %n = mail.domain.tld, %t = domain.tld
$config['default_host'] = array("mail.cybershit.de");

// SMTP server host (for sending mails).
// Enter hostname with prefix tls:// to use STARTTLS, or use
// prefix ssl:// to use the deprecated SSL over SMTP (aka SMTPS)
// Supported replacement variables:
// %h - user's IMAP hostname
// %n - hostname ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
// %t - hostname without the first part
// %d - domain (http hostname $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] without the first part)
// %z - IMAP domain (IMAP hostname without the first part)
// For example %n = mail.domain.tld, %t = domain.tld
$config['smtp_server'] = 'cybershit.de';

// SMTP port (default is 25; use 587 for STARTTLS or 465 for the
// deprecated SSL over SMTP (aka SMTPS))
$config['smtp_port'] = 25;

// SMTP username (if required) if you use %u as the username Roundcube
// will use the current username for login
$config['smtp_user'] = '';

// SMTP password (if required) if you use %p as the password Roundcube
// will use the current user's password for login
$config['smtp_pass'] = '%p';

// provide an URL where a user can get support for this Roundcube installation
// PLEASE DO NOT LINK TO THE ROUNDCUBE.NET WEBSITE HERE!
$config['support_url'] = '';

// Name your service. This is displayed on the login screen and in the window title
$config['product_name'] = 'CYBERSHIIIIT Mail Service';

// this key is used to encrypt the users imap password which is stored
// in the session record (and the client cookie if remember password is enabled).
// please provide a string of exactly 24 chars.
// YOUR KEY MUST BE DIFFERENT THAN THE SAMPLE VALUE FOR SECURITY REASONS
$config['des_key'] = '[removed for security]';

// List of active plugins (in plugins/ directory)
// Debian: install roundcube-plugins first to have any
$config['plugins'] = array(
);

// skin name: folder from skins/
$config['skin'] = 'larry';

// Disable spellchecking
// Debian: spellshecking needs additional packages to be installed, or calling external APIs
//         see defaults.inc.php for additional informations
$config['enable_spellcheck'] = false;

$config['smtp_auth_type'] = 'LOGIN';
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are receiving is because the mail server does not recognise you so won't let you send email through it as you may be a spammer.

There are multiple ways to fix this depending on your scenario. By far the easiest is to register the IP address if the webmail server in postfix.

If you look at the log, postfix is receiving the email from 62.141.44.212 but this address is not listed in the my_networks parameter. You could add this IP to the postfix and restart it.

Alternatively, and more securely, if the webmail client is on the same box as postfix you could change $config['smtp_server']=127.0.0.1 so it communicates across localhost which is already recognised by the SMTP server.

There are other, more complex solutions which will allow user based authentication as well.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me although in my Postfix config there is no my_networks, just mynetworks.